# Fully revoke a user certificates in Hyperledger Fabric Node SDK

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I am lost on how to implement a full revoke functionality on Hyperledger Fabric Node SDK. Is there a way of grabbing a generated CRL and updating the MSP folder or configuration block in a network using Hyperledger Fabric node sdk? I am trying to revoke a certificate, generate a CRL and then update the configuration blocks, and is this last part that I am unsure on how to proceed.

As far as I know this is the flow that I should follow:

- revokeFabricUser
- generateCRL
- fetchConfigBlock
- createConfigUpdatePayloadWithCRL
- updateConfigBlock
- queryAsRevokedUser (this should fail)

I can find options for both revoking and generating CRL but I can´t seem to find anything about how to use the CRL to update the network. Is there a way of doing this whole process using Node SDK? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The node js SDK does not yet support the gencrl option.
https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FABN-1144
It is a pity, because it is very easy to add...